# Joomla insert not working without database prefix

Tags: php, database, model, insert, joomla3.0

I'm trying to add some vale to my DB in Joomla

```
   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $query = $db->getQuery(true);
   // not working
   $query = "INSERT INTO `#__devprofile` (`name`) VALUES ('bnar')";
   $db->setQuery($query);
   echo "execute";
   $db->execute();
```

But when I put the db prefix in front of my `insert` statement everything works as expected like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `hhygd_devprofile` (`name`) VALUES ('bar')";
```

What am I missing here?

thanks in advance

*** UPDATE ***

The issue was that I reinstalled joomla sometimes ago, so the wrong database prefix was set in `configuration.php` , but now it works like a charm

***        ***

Comment: No nothing at all it just does not save

Answer (score 2):

You probably have magic quotes gpc off in joomla. Requirement for joomla installation. But you can change the code to a better joomla format

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('name');
$values = array($db->quote('bnar'));
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__devprofile'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: the issue was the I had the wrong table prefix here because I did not clean my schema :(